# Packet Parsing of bytes in java

Tags: java, sockets, parsing

I am having a problem and tried to find the solution on the net, but couldn't get the exact or similar solution.
The problem I get the data packet on the socket (of-course, would be read as byte[]), and now I want to parse this packet. Initial two byte are integer (type), next two byte are again integer(payload length) and then payload data of 32 byte and next 4 byte are CRC.
Problem here that I unable to get the correct method to parse the data packet, so that I get the type, payload length. If I get to know the way to reading the byte into correct format I can read the payload data as well. So anybody can suggest how to read byte[] into correct type. Thanks in advance.

packet data format of payload(partial) -

Len     Type

2B      Unsigned Short
2B      Unsigned Short
2B      Unsigned Short
2B      Unsigned Short
2B      Unsigned Short
4B      Signed Long
4B      Signed Long
4B      Signed Long
4B      Signed Long

Comment: It depends on the format or encoding of the data. For example is it XDR, or another encoding? This is not really answerable without more info. BTW: why is there a payload length if the payload is 32 bytes?

Comment: @Mark: Payload can be of variable length, that's why there is a field which says the length of the payload. But that shouldn't be the obstacle. Byte ordering is big endian.

Comment: @ug_ Given the additional info, I suggest you undelete your answer

Comment: @MarkRotteveel And when he does so, please delete your erroneous comments. `DataInputStream` does not use XDR, and is not compatible with it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It doesn't use any form of XDR whatsoever. It uses shifts and masks directly. Read the source code. You don't seem to know what XDR even is. It is a library that reads and writes primitives, arrays, strings, unions, and structs, and pointers to any of those. It is not used by Java, and `DataInputStream` doesn't do most of those things.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `DataInputStream` neither 'uses', 'needs', nor 'implements' XDR, contrary to your various claims: it makes no use of the library; implements an incompatible protocol; and it is missing half the features of XDR. That doesn't leave much surviving of your claim. If you have some counter-evidence, produce it: it's your claim, and you have signally failed to support it other than via mere assertion. It would be more correct to state that they both implement a big-endian wire protocol, which isn't much of a statement, as that is the 'network byte order' defined for all IP protocols.

Comment: @EJP I stand corrected. Will remove my comments.

Answer (score 1):

If the byte order is big-endian and there is no padding, you can use `DataInputStream`'s primitive-reading methods: `readShort()` for the type; another `readShort()` for the length; `readFully()` for the payload; and `readInt()` for the CRC.

Comment: how this can parse the byte e.g. initial two bytes forms an int value. Can you provide some code example..

Comment: @Reader read the answer again, if you use readShort() it will exactly do that, read the next 2 bytes as one 16bit short.

Comment: @Reader I've told you exactly what to do. I would expect any competent programmer to be able to reduce this answer to working code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) similar to DataInputStream. It allows to specify the byte order as well:

```
// if you do not use NIO to read from socket, wrap a byte array:
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
short short1 = bb.getShort();
short short2 = bb.getShort();
long long1 = bb.getLong();
```

Comment: I did not try to make sense of your format description. If you specify it as a table it would be easier to read. But I guess the code sample sould be enough to understand the basic pattern to use. There are btw no unsigned types in java, you would have to use the signed ones for reading and then treat the result as unsigned (or mask it into larger types).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `DataInputStream`. However you should carefully examine each method as you use it. In Java integers are 4 bytes, shorts are 2. So when you say read 2 bytes as an integer that method would be `readShort()` then you can cast that to an integer.

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
// populate your buffer

// you could also remove ByteArrayInputStream with the actual input stream.
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
int theInteger = (int)in.readShort(); // reads 2 bytes from the stream and 
                                      // converts them to an integer
```

Comment: Casting to `int` is redundant here.